# How do I update an Amazon EC2 public AMI I created

Tags: amazon-ec2, instance, amazon-ami

I have a public amazon AMI that I created. I have made some changes to an instance of this AMI and would like to update the public AMI with the changes. Not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following question in serverfault which talks about the exact problem you have: https://serverfault.com/questions/79123/re-bundle-or-update-an-ec2-ami